# How to get bar y axis in ascending order starting from zero

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
# Set x_axis, y_axis & Tick Locations
x_axis = final_df["title"]
ticks = np.arange(len(x_axis))
y_axis = final_df["salary"]
plt.bar(x_axis, y_axis, align="center", alpha=0.5, color=["k", "r", "g", "m", "b", "c", "y"])
plt.xticks(ticks, x_axis, rotation="vertical")
plt.ylabel("Salaries ($)")
plt.xlabel("Employee Titles")
plt.title("Average Employee Salary by Title")
#plt.savefig("Average_salary_by_title.png")
plt.show()
```

My graph looks like  pic Bar1 and I want pic Bar2. I've tried different formatting for the y axis, but the end result is not similar to Bar2

[image: pic Bar1]
[image: pic Bar2]

Comment: What is the data type of  `df["salary"]`? It could be that the entries in this column are formatted as strings.

Comment: They're both objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the values in the `"salary"` column are strings.
In this case add the following to your code:

```py
replace_pattern = r'\$|,'  

final_df['salary'].replace(replacement_pattern, '', regex=True, inplace=True)  # replace $ and , 
                                                                               # with an empty string, 
                                                                               # needed for float conversion

final_df['salary'] = final_df['salary'].astype(float)

# continue with barplot
```

This will convert the entries in the `"salary"` column to floats.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list with strings and want to convert it into floats

```
new_list_floats = [float(x) for x in list_name]
```

Comment: OPs question uses dataframes. Please add further details on how your answer can be applied on the OPs specific case. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).